# Syntax of using case in grouping sets

Tags: syntax, hive, case-when, grouping-sets

The Hive query snippet in question is as below:

```
group by
  case
    when inte.subId is not null then 'int'
    else 'ext'
  end,
  taskType,
  result
grouping sets(
  (
    case
      when inte.subId is not null then 'int'
      else 'ext'
    end,  -- line 36
    taskType,
    result
  ),  -- line 39
  (
    taskType,
    result
  )
)
```

The log suggests some syntax error at line 36 and 39:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 36:7 missing ) at ',' near ')'
line 39:3 missing EOF at ',' near ')'
```

Any idea?
If you need more info from me, feel free to comment.

Comment: Use a subquery to define the alias as a column.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Are you suggesting that `case` cannot be used within `grouping sets`, but only column names?

Comment: . . I don't know.  But if you need to get something done, then defining the column in a subquery solves the problem quickly.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Agreed. I will give it a try and let you know the result :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Problem solved. Would you mind posting an answer so I can vote up and accept? If not, I will post one and close the thread myself. Credit goes to you anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is the solution suggested by @GordonLinoff in the comment. Basically, the idea is to use a sub-query where a new column `Category` is selected as

```
case 
  when inte.subId is not null then 'int'
  else 'ext'
end as Category
```

Then, in the outer main query, the group part is simply

```
group by Category, Type, Result
grouping sets(
    (Category, Type, Result),
    (Type, Result)
)
```

As to why the syntax error in the question, we don't know for sure. Maybe, `case` cannot be used within `grouping sets`.